# Repeat main report rows per each subreport row

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a *JasperReports*'s report already implemented using below data structure which prints a main record along with its subreport records. The main and the subreport are placed in the same detail band and the subreport uses the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{employees})` as its data source expression `$F{employees}` being the collection field on the main report data type `Company`.

Company

- Name
- Location
- Employees

Employee

- ID
- Fullname
- etc.

The question is if there is an option in report to repeat the main report columns (Name, Location..) for each subreport record I have for a certain Company?

Basically, I need repeated records in the main report.

I know this is ugly and may look pointless but that is the Business Requirement! Most importantly, I don't want to touch the existing data structure as it's more complex in real case than my example.

Any hint (could be even a hack in JasperReports) is highly appreciated.

Note: I'm using iReport 3.7.3 editor.

Comment: `The question is if there is an option in report to repeat the main report columns (Name, Location..) for each subreport record I have for a certain Company?` - Without passing the data to the subreport - *No*. The subreport has its own datasource

Comment: @AlexK, I don't really understand what you meant. The subreport datasource is part of the main report datasource. (Employees list of a Company). I do not mind any changes on JasperReports to achieve this without modifying the datasource.

Comment: Your question is unclear we can't understand what output you need, nor why you use a subreport if you like to have main data in it, If you must use supreport, pass the main data as parameters and display it on every record in subreport? Try to [edit] the question with example data, expected output, and maybe some relevant jrxml